# How to make BracketsHighlights in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

How to make BracketsHighlights in sublime text 3 like in this photo
[image]

Comment: https://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter is where you can find the quite excellent documentation. The `.sublime-settings` files are also well-documented.

Comment: I know this plugin, but i can't find needs settings for him